# Не запускается plugin в Intellij IDEA 16 Community Edition

Tags: intellij-idea, плагин

Добрый день. Устанавливаю плагин SonarQube Intellij Plugin, IDEA перезапускается, и выдает ошибку, после автоматически выключает плагин.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.7. запустился без проблем.

Comment: как устанавливали плагин и какая ошибка выходит перед отключением плагина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было не в бабине. Я почему-то распоковывал плагин *.zip и ставил один *.jar когда надо было подсунуть весь *.zip